# Location of edited text files on Ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, filesystem

Where does the Ubuntu-touch editor (Edit from the Ubuntu store on the bq aquaris 4.5) save files? I am able to open files I edited on the "local files" menu, but I cannot find where they are stored on the phone (with the file manager).

Similarly, the web-browser seems to download files, but they do not seem to get stored below /home/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files created by the **edIt** app are stored under:

```
~/.local/share/com.ubuntu.developer.pawstr.edit/
```

This is actually a known limitation of the app:

[image]